# How to remove log at start if it's declared as global?

Tags: logging, d

I would like to use global log file. I declared it's as:

```
string logName = "ProcessingLog.txt";
FileLogger fLogger;
static this()
{
    fLogger = new FileLogger(logName);
}
void main()
{
 if (someCondition)
     remove(logName);
}
```

But in `main` on some conditional I would like to recreate it (remove old and create new one), but the problem that I can't call function `removeOldLog();` because current log is blocked by running app.

Removing log inside main is blocking by the same process. I tried to to move `fLogger = new FileLogger(logName);` in before every function that engender log, but than I got runtime error during it's writting. So it's seems that `FileLogger` should be init globally.

What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "blocked"? Are you unable to close the current log? Is it blocked by the same process that wants to remove it or a different process?

Comment: you seem to be missing some kind of locking mechanism for your multi threaded application..

Comment: Could you explain how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should open the file yourself and pass them as parameter:

```
auto file = File("logFile.log", "w");
auto log = new FileLogger(file);

if (some condition)
{
    file.close;
    remove(file.name);
}
```

But remind that if the file gets closed, using the FileLogger for logging will result in undefined behaviour.